# Open Excel files in a new instance

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, windows-registry

How can I open an Excel file directly from the explorer in a new instance?
The registry key *disableMergeInstance* has already been added but this doesn't have an effect on opening files from the windows explorer.

Comment: You are referring to the registry modification described at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/force-excel-to-open-new-instance.  As of Office releases after November 2019 that no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut for Excel.EXE file on the desktop (open its folder and use "RightClick - SendTo - to Desktop(create shortcut)", do not copy the shortcut from Main menu or QuickLaunch pane).

Drag the XLS/XLSX file over the shortcut - it will be opened in new, separate, Excel instance.

You can also open new Excel instance by Alt-Click on its icon or by starting it from command line by `excel /x` command (or create shortcut with this command) - separate process will be started, then open the file.

Comment: As said, it needs to open a new instance when a file in the explorer is clicked. The Excel instance from the taskbar was already enabled with the mentioned Registry key.

Comment: @HYCMedia *when a file in the explorer is clicked* You have not used the word "clicked" or similar. You have told that you need in separate instance. In general it is impossible - or I'm afraid that you must create your own handler library.

Comment: oh yes, I'm sorry. So there is also no way to add like the /x parameter on startup in the registry somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can add that flag to be used when the `.xlsx` file is opened.

First, check out `HKCR\Excel.Sheet\CurVer` and note the `Default` key, which I will hereinafter refer to as `CurVer`.

Navigate to `HKCR\CurVer\shell\Open\command`

Here, change the `Default` key to include `/x` after the `"...EXCEL.EXE"` and before `"%1"` so it should look similar to: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /x "%1"`

This will add the `/x` flag when opening an Excel file.

NOTE: It will not use that flag when opening a `CSV` file. That flag is located at `HKCR\Excel.CSV\shell\Open\command`

Similarly, other document TYPEs that are opened by Excel can be modified under their respective `HKCR\Excel.TYPE`

Comment: Not working for me.